# How do I ensure a pop-up form opens in the centre of the screen?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

## Background

I have a Access 2010 database and want to create a pop-up progress screen when it does an update of the tables (can take a second to a few minutes).

I can create a pop-up form without any borders etc and display the information I require but I can't for the life of me get the form to open in the centre of the screen.

I have tried setting the "Auto Center" (and "Auto Resize") to true ("Yes") but that didn't seem to have any effect.

*Note: I have made the form pop-up by setting "Pop Up" to true.*

## Question

How can I open a pop-up form in the centre of the screen in MS Access 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you open the popup form can you do

```
DoCmd.MoveSize x, y
```

x and y are the x,y co-ords of the top left corner of the form

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. I was hoping that the "Auto Center" option did what it sounds like it does. I currently don't have an OnLoad for this form. Also I would need to get the size of the screen and the size of the pop-up form before finally do a calculation to work out the top left of the pop-up's new location. So will keep this as an option if it isn't possible to get Access' "Auto Center" function to work. Don't really want all that extra code to maintain. ;) Thank though I have marked it up and if no other option will mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution that takes advantage of how MS Access handles maximizing and restoring windows.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.SetFocus
    DoCmd.Maximize
    DoCmd.Restore
End Sub
```

This seems to place the popup close to the center consistently for me.  It doesn't always land in the exact center though.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is for the primary screen:**

Here you can find a way to get the screen size of the primary screen:
[How to retrieve screen size/resolution in MS Access VBA to re-size a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843310/how-to-retrieve-screen-size-resolution-in-ms-access-vba-to-re-size-a-form)

in your vba code, after you open the form, you can use

```
DoCmd.MoveSize right, down, width, height
```

to resize and move the popup around the primary screen.

**Arguments**

| Name | Required/Optional | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Right | Optional | Variant | The new horizontal position of the window's upper-left corner, measured from the left edge of its containing window. |
| Down | Optional | Variant | The new vertical position of the window's upper- |
| Width | Optional | Variant | The window's new width. |
| Height | Optional | Variant | The window's new height. |

```
YourRightArg = (ScreenWidth / 2) + (PopupFormWidth / 2) 
YourDownArg = (ScreenHeight / 2) + (PopupFormHeight / 2)
```

**My personal solution**

I used Form.move to move my popup around. Left and top are in reference to the active Access Window instead of the primary screen.

```
Sub Move(Left, [Top], [Width], [Height])
Member of Access.Form
```