# How to retrieve screen size/resolution in MS Access VBA to re-size a form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I have two popup forms (parent/child) that I want to be able to automatically re-size depending on the size of the screen.

How can I retrieve the size of the screen in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Access 2010 64 bit, you will need to add `PtrSafe` before `Function`.

```
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "User32" _
    Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Sub ScreenRes()
Dim w As Long, h As Long
    w = GetSystemMetrics32(0) ' width in points
    h = GetSystemMetrics32(1) ' height in points

End Sub
```

For VBA 64 bits

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "User32" _
    Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
```

More info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210603

Answer (score 3):

For VBA, a simpler (and therefore possibly more portable) solution might be:

```
Application.UsableHeight
Application.UsableWidth
```

As found at [Adjust userforms to fit in screen](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.programming/EH8_Jr6lhrY).  I am using this successfully with Word 2007 VBA.  In my case, `Application.UsableWidth` gives the actual screen width, `Application.UsableHeight` gives the actual screen height, minus the height of Windows' taskbar.

Comment: This is clever for using in MS Word, but in MS Access 2013 the .UsableWidth property does not seem to exist.  Sure would be nice if it did, though.

Comment: This dont work in MS Access, sadly.