# Relationship between MS Access Form and Screen Resolution

Tags: forms, ms-access, resize, ui-design

I am developing MS Access application for a client where most of the desktop monitors are with the resolution of `1366x768` or `1600 X 900`

My development desktop has resolution of `1920x1080`

Is there any documentation which will help to know what should be the ideal size of the form (Height and Width) in `CMS` so that the users don't have to scroll.

I *of-course* Googled and also searched on stack overflow but could not find any post or question.

Comment: (1/2) The horizontal and vertical anchor properties of controls you place on forms can help position them on the user's monitor size relative to where you positioned them in design view. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Make-controls-stretch-shrink-or-move-as-you-resize-a-form-51fd88e0-43d3-4070-a298-18ba273f4cf8 It may also be worth looking at pixel-to-centimetre converters online to ensure the minimum size of a control you create (e.g. a subform) is small enough for the most common monitors...

Comment: (2/2) There's also this answer on SO, which explains how to retrieve screen resolution in VBA, which might be useful should you want to resize forms and controls dynamically with VBA: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11843637/2140244