# Get Windows display zoom value

Tags: excel, vba, screen-resolution

Is there any way to get display zoom value of Windows? The 200% in the picture is exactly what I would like to get.
[image]

This question is only half the means to achieve another purpose, which is formulated in that question: [Excel Shape position disturbed by Windows Display Zoom settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862340/excel-shape-position-disturbed-by-windows-display-zoom-settings)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843310/how-to-retrieve-screen-size-resolution-in-ms-access-vba-to-re-size-a-form) out and see if it helps

Comment: @PankajJaju I need something different. Please check out my ultimate goal linked at the end of my question. The bug shown there can be reproduced with whatever resolution, if display zoom is set up to 125%, so knowing just resolution does not help.  Nevertheless you linked to interesting method of getting screen resolution.

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve this information with a WIN32-API call

```
Option Explicit

Private Const LOGPIXELSX As Long = 88

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumDisplayMonitors Lib "user32" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByRef lprcClip As Any, ByVal lpfnEnum As LongPtr, ByVal dwData As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function EnumDisplayMonitors Lib "user32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByRef lprcClip As Any, ByVal lpfnEnum As Long, ByVal dwData As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Function GetDpi() As Long
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hdcScreen As LongPtr
        Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hdcScreen As Long
        Dim hWnd As Long
    #End If
    
    hWnd = GetActiveWindow()
    hdcScreen = GetDC(hWnd)

    Dim iDPI As Long
    iDPI = -1

    If (hdcScreen) Then
        iDPI = GetDeviceCaps(hdcScreen, LOGPIXELSX)
        ReleaseDC hWnd, hdcScreen
    End If

    GetDpi = iDPI
End Function
```

This will result in `192` for eg `200%`:

- 96  – Smaller 100%
- 120 – Medium 125%
- 144 – Larger 150%
- 192 – Extra Large 200%
- 240 – Custom 250%
- 288 – Custom 300%
- 384 – Custom 400%
- 480 – Custom 500%

Comment: The problem with GetDpi function is that it does not respond to Windows display zoom change. It returns correct value and sticks to it later when I change the zoom value. Even restart of Excel does not help. Probably restart of Windows would help but I have not tested that.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Yes there might be a logoff/login required. But you wouldn't change this setting during working anyway. You set this once you setup your computer and then you will never touch it again. So I see no issue here.

Comment: No, on the contrary, the zoom is not once and for all. Imagine a situation in which a user suddenly disconnects a laptop from an external monitor. There is another zoom value on the external monitor and another on the laptop. I need to catch this change.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Well, If the API dosen't reflect that change who can know it then. I mean using the API means we ask Windows to give us the value. If Windows itself dosn't give us the correct value then I assume there is no other way to retrieve it.

Comment: This value in Windows changes. Actually, you may change it and then try the function you proposed. It is the matter of retrieving it.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin yes I understand that the value in Windows changed. What I tried to say is if the API (which is part of Windows) doesn't reflect that change then there is probably nothing else that reflects that change. Which means logoff/login is probably the only solution to get the correct value again.

Comment: Your answer opens way to get the result. It must be combined with the function returning screen resolution https://stackoverflow.com/a/11843637/1903793 suggested in the comment of Pankaj Jaju. The screen resolution function responds immediately to the change of the screen resolution. So knowing that the resolution changed and zoom remained the same we can probably derive the true zoom value under some assumptions. If not better solution is proposed in few days I will accept your solution.

Comment: If the resolution changed that doesn't automatically mean that dhe DPI changed too. You can change the resolution and keep the DPI the same. Resolution and DPI are completely independend values. No way to "guess" the DPI by knowing the resolution.

Comment: @PEH yes, but in my practical case, if resolution changed and zoom is the same then I may assume that the monitor is unplugged.

Comment: any possibility to get the values from multiple monitors connected to the computer?

Comment: @smartini I changed it so it shows the result of the active window. If you put the active window on the monitor you want to read out you get its zoom. See my edit.