# Excel Shape position disturbed by Windows Display Zoom settings

Tags: excel, vba, position, screen-resolution

I would like to get accurate Shape position in Excel. I noticed that [Shape.Top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.top) is being disturbed by Windows Display Zoom settings.

To reproduce the bug, please right click on a sheet name > View code > and paste the VBA code in the sheet VBA editor.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes("BlueRectangle").Delete

    Dim sh As Object
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, ActiveCell.Left, ActiveCell.Top, ActiveCell.Width, ActiveCell.Height)
    sh.Name = "BlueRectangle"
End Sub
```

This code creates Rectange shape in the double clicked cell. Everything works fine as long as the display zoom of Windows settings is set up to 100%. However when we change display zoom in Windows settings to 125% then the rectangle is created in a slightly different place than the Active cell. There is a difference of 1 row in the location height for every 100 rows of Excel. So, when I click **A100** cell then the Rectangle is created in **A99** cell.

I would like to correct the location Rectangle creation so that Windows Zoom Display is taken into account.

Here is behavior with 100% Display Zoom:
[image]

Here is a buggy behavior I would like to fix which happens with 125% Display Zoom:
[image]

Here is the related inconspicuous challenge I threw on SO which might be a milestone in answering this question:
[Get Windows display zoom value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861661/get-windows-display-zoom-value)

Comment: Would it help to get the [cursor position as cell address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271141/vba-get-cursor-position-as-cell-address)? Or would that throw the same wrong address?

Comment: @JvdV the suggested by you solution returns even more inaccurate results then the bug presented above. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I'm working with 150% and positioning is correct in Excel even for the very last cells.

Also there should be nothing need to be corrected.

But there might be some issues with your code:

- Avoid `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` and use `Target.Parent` this is more reliable.
- Also avoid using `ActiveCell` and use `Target` because `ActiveCell` might not have changed to the cell you clicked on yet. `Target` is the cell you doubleclicked *not* `ActiveCell`.

Give the follwing a try. I doupt that the DPI is the issue and I suspect it is a `ActiveCell` related issue.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.Parent.Shapes("BlueRectangle").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activate error handling after an expected error

    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = Target.Parent.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Target.Left, Target.Top, Target.Width, Target.Height)
    shp.Name = "BlueRectangle"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hat off my head, PEH. You found the reason.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Since this solved your issue the only explanation I can imagine is that: Changing the DPI to something other than 100% probably slowed down your computer so much that if you double clicked on a cell triggering the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` was faster than Excel changing the `ActiveCell` to the one you double clicked. • So this is just another example why you shoud **always** try to avoid `ActiveCell`.